# Hiding the field in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working with jasper report-4.5.0.I want to hide a field in jasper based on the flag value.Below is tha code which i am using in columnHeader band.

```
<staticText>
  <reportElement x="365" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
  <box>
    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
  </box>
  <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
    <font isBold="true"/>
  </textElement>
  <text><![CDATA[TotalCharge]]></text>
</staticText>
```

and below code i am using in detail band.

```
<textField>
  <reportElement x="365" y="0" width="100" height="20">
  <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{dataType}]]></printWhenExpression>

  </reportElement>
  <box>
    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
  </box>
  <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
    <font size="8"/>
  </textElement>
  <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{chargeTotal}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

i am declaring the parameter in jrxml as

```
<parameter name="dataType" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
```

the value to this parameter is coming from java class.If it is the false value i dont want to display this chargeTotal column.What i am doing wrong in my code.I am not getting.Any one can point me where i am doing wrong its urgent to me.

Answer (score 4):

The code snippets you provided for the textfield look correct, but if you are wanting to hide the column header also you need to also add a `printWhenExpression` for it.

```
<staticText>
  <reportElement x="365" y="0" width="100" height="20">
      <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{dataType}]]></printWhenExpression>
  </reportElement>
  <box>
    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
  </box>
  <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
    <font isBold="true"/>
  </textElement>
  <text><![CDATA[TotalCharge]]></text>
</staticText>
```

Edit: Actually, you have the conditional value backwards. If you want to show the column when `dataType` is true, your `printWhenExpression` needs to look like:

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{dataType}]]></printWhenExpression>
```